# Ionic 2 live reload server error when trying to debug Ionic project with VS Code

Tags: cordova, ionic2, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to debug an Ionic 2 project (error occurs for any sample project) with VS Code and Cordova Tools Extension. I choose default option "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)" and receive following error message after hitting the run button:

"The Ionic live reload server exited unexpectedly
Error in the Ionic live reload server:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:53703"

System Information:

Mac OS 10.12.4,
VS Code 1.12.1,
Cordova Tools (for VS Code) 1.2.7

launch.json entry (error occurs even when "ionicLiveReload": false):

```
    {
        "name": "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)",
        "type": "cordova",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "serve",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "devServerAddress": "localhost",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "ionicLiveReload": true,
        "devServerTimeout": 120000
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was bug in extension related to killing process tree, which is fixed in dev version (master branch), but it hasn't released yet. You need to kill these processes manually.

`ps -ax | grep ionic` - find pid of this process

`kill -9 <PID>` - kill it

Run ionic serve again.

P.S. There is not fully support for Ionic2 project in v1.2.7, but it will be in the next release.